# IE9/IE7 select tag behave different

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

```
<select size="4" name="lbxEmployees" id="lbxEmployees" disabled="disabled" class="FormDropDown" style="width:100%;">
        <option value="1">jim jubak</option>
        <option value="2">Peyton Andrew</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">Pat smith</option>
        <option value="4">Mark Smith</option>
        <option value="5">Kobe Bryan</option>
</select>
```

The above code renders differently on IE9 and IE7. Can someone explain why? The select box is disabled in both browsers, but one shows the selected value (IE7) while the other does not (IE9).

Comment: ...Because they're different browsers.

Comment: Oh, and it might help to mention which one does what.

Comment: i did small test and found out that disabled is the key here. IE7 shows selected item highlighted even its disabled. IE9 doesn't.

Comment: Ah, thank you. The difference is probably because Microsoft rewrote most of the rendering engine between IE8 and IE9. There probably isn't anything that can be done about it.

Comment: yeap.. i tried in mozila it works same as IE7.

Comment: I added an EDIT, just to tell about security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting , starting with an enabled check box, I tried this as a poss way to fool IE9 ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 document.getElementById("lbxEmployees").value = 3;

 document.getElementById("lbxEmployees").disabled=true;

</script>
```

didn't work. did in IE7

( if your goal is to presnt to the user the selected value and have to have the select box ) looks like we might need to do something like ...

```
  <div id="EmployeesDiv">

    Employee:

    <select name="lbxEmployees" id="lbxEmployees">
      <option value="1">jim jubak</option>
      <option value="2">Peyton Andrew</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="3">Pat smith</option>
      <option value="4">Mark Smith</option>
      <option value="5">Kobe Bryan</option>
    </select>

  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload = function() {
 var selectBox = document.getElementById("lbxEmployees");
 var val = (selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;

/* remove select box and replace */
document.getElementById("EmployeesDiv").innerHTML ="Employee: "+val;
}
</script>
```

your app might have a simpler way of course, the IE9 thing got me thinking ...

*Not great if the reason for the disable is security, do all this on the sever side before page print if so!

Comment: you did mention something that i want to do. disable is part of security and that is the reason i need this functionality.

Comment: there is security and some business logic.. not sure why you say its NOT Great.. sometimes business rules requires somethings which is unique.. anyway.. I COULDN'T FIND RIGHT ANSWER.. but you had some logical solution so i will mark your answer..

Comment: Hi, Thanks, what I meant by not great was - disabling an input field can easily be re-enabled with client side tools these days, and so, not to be relied on, if the reason for the disable is security.

Comment: Understand.. but there are lot more involve than just one field in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because IE9 is a different browser. IE7 was released back in 2006, while IE9 in 2011. There is no point of showing what is default in something that isn't enabled, so they've disabled it..

EDIT:
If you want to disable it because of security, you should enforce that on the server-side. If a hacker copies your source code, and removes the "disabled" part, they will be able to change and include that information as well.